# Connection between phase space and Orbit, why the Orbit is in the phase space?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the ODE $$\dot x=f(x),$$
where $f:U\subset \mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^n$.

In [wikipedia], the define the flow through $x_0$ by the function function $\Phi^t:U\to \mathbb R^n$ being such that $$\frac{d}{dt}\Phi^t(x_0)=f(\Phi^t(x_0)).$$
in other word, $t\mapsto \Phi^t(x_0)$ is the unique solution (if $f$ is well enough) of the Cauchy problem $$\begin{cases}\dot x=f(x)\\ x(0)=x_0\end{cases}.$$

Now, they say that the orbit through $x_0$ is $$\mathcal O_x=\{\varphi ^t(x_0)\mid t\geq 0\},$$ and they say that it's included in the phase space. This is what I don't understand. For example, consider $f(x)=x$. Then the flow is given by $$\Phi^t(x)=e^{t}x.$$
Therefore, the Orbit through $x_0$ is $$\{e^{t}x_0\mid t\geq 0\}.$$
For me the Phase space has coordinate $(x,\dot x)$, and this really doesn't look in the phase space but really in $\mathbb R$. Can someone explain the connection ?

Comment: The phase space has the composition $(x,\dot x)$ for second order equation like in mechanical systems. Here the equation is in first-order form, so the state space has the composition $(x)$.

Comment: The phase space is the space where you can interpret your equation as a first order equation (or system if your unknown is multidimensional). A single equation of order n can be thought as a first order system for $n$ unknowns (the successive derivatives). The phase space you mentioned is for a second order equation.

Comment: @LutzL: Something is still not clear... For example, take $\ddot x+x=0$. Then it's a second order, right ? Then, solution are given by $x(t)=(A\cos(t)+B\sin(t), -A\sin(t)+B\cos(t))$. So if $x(0)=(1,0)$, then the orbit is $O=\{(\cos(t),-\sin(t))\mid t\in\mathbb R\}$. This is simply in $\mathbb R^2$, not in the phase space... (it's just the trace of the solution, and the solution is a function $\mathbb R\to \mathbb R^2$). So why do we need phase space ?

Comment: No, $x$ is just a scalar function, the pair you wrote down is actually $(x(t),\dot x(t))$, so indeed already the element of the phase space.